# How to check if all elements of a list are different

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<int>` items. How can I check if all the items are different with a LINQ query?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ this was the opposite as I wanted to check if they were all different and not all the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the meantime I solved it with: 
`CurrentList.Distinct().Count() < CurrentList.Count()`

Answer (score 3):

Some of the other alternatives are

Option 1

```
(!list.GroupBy(c => c).Any(c => c.Count()>1))
```

Option 2

```
list.GroupBy(c => c).All(c => c.Count() == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is using a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1):

```
var areDifferent= new HashSet<int>(CurrentList).Count==CurrentList.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

This more beautiful:

```
var isDifferentData = !int.Equals(CurrentList.Distinct().Count(),CurrentList.Count())
```